# How to validate Radio Buttons in a Table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have some Radio Buttons that creates in run time and they are inside of a table.How I can check that one of the surly selected using jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Using tables for layout, aren't we? `:)`

Comment: Are the radio buttons part of the same radio button group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this....

```
 $('#table tbody tr input[type=radio]').each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('checked'));
    });
```

or

There are many ways to do that, e.g., using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and the [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) traversal method:

```
$("table tr td input[name=something]:radio").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("tr").css("border", "1px solid red");
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

or you can do like this .....

define a class on your radio button items, basically your client side HTML should look like `<input id="answer-2_1" type="radio" name="answer-2" value="0" class="myrdo" />`

now, in your js code, simply wire up an event handler on the class

```
$(".myrdo").bind("click",function(){if($(this).attr("checked")==true) {alert($(this).val);} });
```

the above command will simply alert the value of the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution:

```
if ( $( 'input[type="radio"]', '#table' ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
    // validation passes
}
```